# How to isolate commits on a contaminated, merged topic branch, in order to apply them to a different branch?

Tags: git, release

**update** tl;dr: don't let yourselves get into this situation, it is avoidable.

How can I isolate the `f` commits that were committed on the feature branch below? The goal is to apply them to the release-candidate branch, without bringing in anything from master or wip-feature.

In most cases, the merges from master to the feature branch are not required for the feature to function. We want to prove that that is the case, on the release-candidate branch.

```
                   /-F0----F1--\-F2    wip-feature (not ready to release)
                  /             \ 
m0------**-------m1--m2--m3--m4--m5--m6--m7--m8    master
 \               /           \      / \      / 
  \             /             \-f0-/   \-f1-/    feature (probably ready to release, but not clean)
   \           /       
    \-r0-----r1--r2--r3    release-candidate (each "merge" is an isolated feature, or a hotfix merging backwards from production)
     \      /
      \-p0-/    production (receives wholesale merges from release-candidate, and hotfixes)
```

That merge from `m6` to the feature branch is unfortunate, that really complicates things, but people always seem to find reasons to do stuff like that (maintaining compatibility with other work in progress, incorporating improvements to the dev environment, etc.)

So far, I have been doing a `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`, and visually inspecting the tree in order to put together a big cherrypick operation. I cherry-pick to an intermediate branch that is based off of the destination branch, so that I can apply it by merging; that merge is something that I can revert, unlike a cherry-pick. The problem with this is that when there are a large number of commits on the feature branch, a large number of feature branches being worked on in parallel, and a relatively long timespan, it is difficult to follow the thread of that one branch.

I would check out the feature branch and interactively rebase it onto release-candidate, dropping `m5` and `m6` in the process, but when I tried that, `m2` and `m3` were included in the rebase operation, and this is a simplification; there were actually ~50 commits that I would have had to drop. This could work, but it is also very manual and somewhat error prone.

The end result that I am looking for, viewed from the release-candidate branch, would be something like this:

```
--r2--r3--f0--f1  release-candidate
```

If that passes QA on release-candidate, then I would merge the whole thing to production and tag a release. If it doesn't then I would revert the merge that introduced the `f*` commits, so that we would still have the option of merging release-candidate to production.

I need find a way to isolate the `f*` commits without missing anything or picking up any commits from other branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this really is just a terrible idea. Devs might think that their feature resides entirely on a single branches commits, but if that branch was contaminated by a merge from another branch, then from that point on the programmer is coding against a new environment, whether they are aware of that or not.

For us, we have tried several variants of the [gitflow](https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) workflow in the past, and run into integration issues at merge time. We also wanted to do functional and system tests on each feature branch in isolation, but found that setting up feature branch test environments was not something that we (I) could automate for a reasonable amount of effort, considering the large number of integrated services in our main project.

Now we are doing something similar to trunk based deployment, with feature toggles and a dedicated QA team. It doesn't have the purity of isolated feature branches, but for some reason, it is working really well for us. Integration happens early, and is relatively painless. We do still work on a feature in a separate branch, but we rebase it onto trunk whenever trunk is updated. Our history is more linear too, which it nice.

But most importantly, we will not merge trunk into a work in progress branch anymore. That's just sloppy, it can't be allowed. Rebase onto trunk, then merge into it. If more work is needed, consider starting a new branch for that, so that you can still rebase in private (don't rebase pushed branches). If the branch fails hard after merging, then revert. Revert the revert on a new branch, fix the problem, and merge again.

So, as for the original question, it is a fallacy to think that you can extract a feature by picking the commits from a messy branch; the question is wrong.